# Raspberry pi 4 - Slow read speed, but high write speed over network from pc

Tags: raspbian-buster

I setup my rp4 as a torrentbox with raspbian Buster, deluge and samba share i followed this article --> https://techwiztime.com/article/best-raspberry-pi-torrentbox/

I have some issues, maybe someone here can help me!?

-If i try to copy af file from my computer to the disk connected to rp4 i get nice transfer speed ~100 MB/S

-But if i copy from the disk connected to rp4 to my PC i get slow speed ~4 MB/s

Details about my setup:
-Raspbian is installed on a SanDisk Extreme Pro 32Gb
-The harddrive that is connected is a SATA 3 7200rpm Toshiba with USB 3
-PC and rp4 is connected to 1gbit router with CAT 6 cables

**UPDATE**
I´ve made the exact same setup on my old rp3 and i get full speeds when reading and writing from the same external disk. (10-12 MB/S, read and write)

Do anyone have a suggestion how to get higher read speeds on my new rp4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the drive is formatted ntfs you will get poor speeds, especially if you have not installed ntfs-3g on the Pi. Ntfs on Linux uses CPU. Also is it mounted via fstab? If so, is the fstab line good? I have a new Raspberry Pi 4 and I have just added a portable 2 TB WD Elements USB-3.0 drive which is on a Samba share. I formatted the drive with ext4 and I can use the USB3 and gigabit ethernet properly. I get 100 MB/s in both directions. Using ntfs it was 18-20 MB/s write and 40-50 MB/s read.

UPDATE - I see you say your external drive is a "SATA 3". Are you using a USB - to SATA adapter? You should be aware that some of these (and some USB-3 drives) have issues on the R Pi 4 that were not seen on previous Pi versions. It's to do with the Pi 4 enabling the USB Attached SCSI (UAS) driver by default, unlike earlier R Pis (1 to 3). There is a [sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=245931) at the Raspberry Pi Forums, which may be worth reading.

Comment: I have updated this answer.

Comment: The drive is EXT4 and mounted via fstab. Yes i think it is a USB to SATA adapter. It is a external 3.5" chassis i use for the drive. Ok, thank you for the link.